# map and set insert function won't resolve

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

My assignment is to use some combination of std  set, map or multimap to implement a collection of courses with prereqs.  The assignment was a bit open ended and I'm having a hard time getting started. Under courseCollections.h I have the following

```
//A collection of courses with no duplicates.
typedef std::set<Course, less<Course> > CourseSet;
//A map from a course to zero or more other courses.
typedef std::multimap<Course, Course, less<Course>> CourseMap;
```

In a constructor for CourseCatalog  I declare the following

```
CourseSet coursesOffered;
CourseMap enables;
```

I'm trying to implement a function to add courses to the set and map but I get compilation errors when I try to use enables.insert.  Why is this not working as I would expect?

```
void addCourses (
        const Course& course1,
        const Course& prereqOfCourse1)
{
    enables.insert(course1, prereqOfCourse1); //error Method 'insert' could not be resolved
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `enables.insert()` takes a single argument of type `CourseSet::value_type`, which in this case is `std::pair<const Course, Course>`.  You are giving it two arguments instead.  There are two normal ways to solve this problem:

```
enables.insert(std::make_pair(course1, prereqOfCourse));
```

Here you are giving `insert()` the type it wants.  The second solution may be more what you want, though:

```
enables.emplace(course1, prereqOfCourse);
```

`enables.emplace` takes as its arguments the arguments to the constructor of `CourseSet::value_type`.  This is a little less verbose, and probably easier to read and understand.

*Note: `std::multimap<T>::emplace` requires C++ 11 support (at least).*

Comment: Thanks. It seems like there is a deeper problem because the compiler won't resolve enables at all. I'm working with pretty vague instructions on what the instructor expects so I reached out to him directly but thank you for confirming that what I was expecting wasn't way off.

Answer (score 3):

`std::map::insert()` takes one parameter, a `std::pair`, and not two separate parameters.

```
enables.insert(std::make_pair(course1, prereqOfCourse1));
```